# Is there a word that means the opposite of "to capitalize"?

Tags: single-word-requests, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an antonym for “capitalize” (as in letter-case)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14575/is-there-an-antonym-for-capitalize-as-in-letter-case)

Is there a word, preferably *not* from the realm of computer programming, that means the opposite of "to capitalize"?

In programming, there are scores of (silly) ways to tell someone to undo capitalization:  downcase that, shush that first letter, etc.

Comment: *Uncapitalization* is in use.

Comment: Just reading the title, my first thought was 'to squander'.