# What is the antonyms of "capitalize"?

Tags: expressions, nouns, terminology, antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there an antonym for “capitalize” (as in letter-case)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14575/is-there-an-antonym-for-capitalize-as-in-letter-case)

What is the antonyms of "capitalize"?

I am referring to the following meaning ([original reference](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/capitalize)):

> *capitalize*:
>
> to write or print (text) with the first letter of (a word or words) in capital letters.